# Array declaration comparity

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently cleaning up a bit of nasty code. This code defines to an existing array several new keys in quite the depth:

```
$form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see']['title'] = 'Hello';
$form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see']['body'] = 'This be a greeting';
$form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see']['etc'] = 'This does nothing';
$form['another_long_key_name_right']['title'] = 'Hello!';
$form['another_long_key_name_right']['body'] = 'This be a greeting!';
$form['another_long_key_name_right']['etc'] = 'This does nothing.';
```

I would prefer to define this as such:

```
$arr_form = array('long_key_name_right_here_you_see' => array('title' => 'Hello',
                                                              'body'  => 'This be a greeting',
                                                              'etc'   => 'This does nothing'
),
                  'another_long_key_name_right'      => array('title' => 'Hello!',
                                                              'body'  => 'This be a greeting!',
                                                              'etc'   => 'This does nothing.'));

$form = ($arr_form + $form);
```

- Can I always count on my prefered approach to do the same result as existing case?
- Would my prefered approach be considered unclear and pointless?

Essentially, I just feel that huge walls of identical keys defined in rows looks a bit ugly in the code, but maybe that's just my mind that's picky.

[**Relevant PHP Documentaion**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand
>   array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the
>   left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the
>   right-hand array will be ignored.

**Note:**

The accepted answer helped me in *my* case. This question doesn't necessarily have one true answer but might inspire others and as it did me .

Comment: Apart from the fact that the syntax is off (you want `$form += $defaultValues`) this is the way to go.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct approach? The array has existing values and keys needs to be overrided. Please check the documentation I linked in the question and share your thoughts.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. In that case your syntax is correct. I would prefer to use `$form = array_merge($form, $defaultValues)` instead to make it very clear to the reader that you are *supposed* to override values (that's the difference between `+` and `array_merge`), but the end result is the same.

Comment: Enforcing what Jon says. Try  `$form = array_merge($form, $arr_form);`, it is ok, and more stable than union operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're working with a single array cell, I'd probably use a short pointer to the long key to improve readability. Personally, I dislike overusing the array() function call as it's a bit harder to read.

A pointer will not take extra memory space as a temporary variable would.

So this:

```
$form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see']['title'] = 'Hello';
$form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see']['body'] = 'This be a greeting';
$form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see']['etc'] = 'This does nothing';
```

Would become this:

```
$target_form =& $form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see'];

$target_form = array(); // In case it's undefined. Drop this if it's not empty.
$target_form['title'] = 'Hello';
$target_form['body'] = 'This be a greeting';
$target_form['etc'] = 'This does nothing';

unset($target_form);
```

Note that the unset statement will unset the pointer reference, not the contents of the array. It's only necessary to avoid overwriting your data if you decide to reuse `$target_form` later on.

*This probably deserves more attention than a mere comment:
Be careful around pointers. It is easy to overwrite data and hard to debug unless used carefully.*

Comment: Wow this approach looks quite beautiful! Always a pleasure to learn new ways to style the code. I will try it out and accept accordingly.

Comment: @RobinCastlin It might look good, but you should always be careful around pointers. Make sure you know what you are doing or debugging accidental overwrites will haunt your nightmares. :)

Comment: Pointers/references are great for making code simpler and more readable, just ensure that you give them meaningful names and avoid overwriting them (without a good reason).

Comment: Thanks for the warnings :) May help my hair being dispatched by my hairdresser rather than by my own hands.

Answer (score 1):

`$arr_form += $form;`  would not be given you your desired output .. you should reverse the variables instead example:

```
$form = array();
$arr_form = array(
        'title' => 'Hello',
        'body' => 'This be a greeting',
        'etc' => 'This does nothing'
);
$form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see'] = $arr_form;
var_dump($form);
```

Comment: If I read the documentation right, `$form += $arr_form` won't override identical keys.

Comment: Why would you even bother setting the `$arr_form` variable in the first place? It'll stay in memory even though we don't need it at all.

Comment: If you always want to make you `override` with minimal overhead then just assign the key

Comment: @h2ooooooo they are cases where sub modules have their config which can work independently or grouped with the main configuration and even $form  can be a session variable

Comment: In my case I simply find it more appealing to define the long key name once instead of three times as in the case. I doubt there would be a perfomance loss worth noticing by this practice. The answer has been updated a bit. Your answer works cleanly without doubt in first example though.

Answer (score 1):

Each person has different tastes, and languages ​​(PHP, Python, etc.) generally allow you to do the same thing
in various ways, serving all tastes and style codes ...

---

### The `with` statment idea

The @MaximKumpan's answer is like to use a [`with..as` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012565/287948) of Python and other languages.
*Imagine* something like this,

```
   //if not exist, $form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see']=array();    
   with $form['long_key_name_right_here_you_see'] as $f {
     $f['title'] = 'Hello';
     $f['body'] = 'This be a greeting';
     $f['etc'] = 'This does nothing';
   }
```

NOTE: only imagine (!), the real PHP code is `$f =& $form['...']`, ending with `unset($f)`, as Max's code.

### A general config problem/solution

Your problem reminds me of something we already saw before in various configuration scripts.
Here we have a [typical example of Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileExtensions), offering two styling flavors, for two tastes:

```
$w = array( 'png', 'jpg', 'jp2', 'webp', '...'); // original

$w[] = 'pdf';  // "add one by one item" taste
$w[] = '...';

$new = array( 'pdf', 'ppt', 'jp2' );
$w   = array_merge( $w, $new );  // "add all itens" taste
```

And you remember another way

```
$w = $w + $new;
// CAUTION: array_merge, "+" and "+=" are not exactly the same thing!
```

But, your problem is not merge commom arrays, **it is about "merging associative arrays"**... You can do it as well (!), [see
this other similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13170261/287948) 
(see also [array_merge_recursive function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)).

For your example, `array_merge` is also a valid and readable solution (replace  `$arr_form + $form` in yor code):

```
 $form = array_merge($form, $arr_form); // not the same as (arr_form,$form)!
```

Mediawiki (above link) is an example of "**best practices**", and (I also) prefer `array_merge` function than array union operator ("+").

Comment: Thanks for input. Though I think you mean `$w = ($new + $w) // not necessarily equal to $w += $new;` is the way I shown.

Comment: It is only a "peripheral comment", thanks, I edited adding "CAUTION"... PHP have different behaviours with each "array merge taste" :-)   But your problem is about **associative arrays**, so I also complete with the "associative solution" with `array_merge`.