# PHP Array merge two keyed arrays into a single array

Tags: php, arrays

I am two arrays both containning 4 keyed values. They both have the same columns - how would I merge them like so:

Array 1:

```
Author|Download|Rating|Count
person|23      | 5    | 0
peter |45      | 4    | 0
```

Array 2:

```
Author|Download|Rating|Count
      | 0      |0     | 3
      | 0      |0     | 5
```

Becomes a single array:

```
Author|Download|Rating|Count
person|23      | 5    | 3
peter |45      | 4    | 5
```

This is done via two SQL Queries like shown:

Array 1

```
 while ($stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            $array = array (
                    'Author' => $author,
                    'Download' => $download,
                    'Rating' => $rating,
                    'Count' => '',
                    );                  
        }
```

Array 2

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            $array = array (
                    'Author' => '',
                    'Download' => '',
                    'Rating' => '',
                    'Count' => $count,
                    );                  
        }
```

How would I get these into a single Array?
I know one could do this via loop but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried fetching result using single sql query ?

Comment: Would be better to get the data in only one SQL statement in the first place.

Comment: This is not a merge, this is an output by arbitrary rule - write your own function.

Comment: Use a join in your query.

Comment: Use a join, or just stop putting the blank values in the arrays and then merge them.

Comment: try this guy here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170230/php-combine-two-associative-arrays-into-one-array