# PHP - How to check two arrays and search for matching keys and merge the values

Tags: php, arrays

How to check two arrays and search for matching keys and merge the values of the 1st array with the matching keys of the second array.Please help me as I'm new to this.

example :

```
1st array = {id => 11,name => 'name',age => 18 }


2nd array = {id,name,age,school}
```

I want to get the result by adding the matching values to the 2nd array

```
2nd array = {id => 11,name => 'name',age => 18,school => }
```

Comment: i think this is answer you are searching for [stackoveflow ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170230/php-combine-two-associative-arrays-into-one-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simple way is looping

```
$first= array('id' => 11,'name' => 'name','age' => 18 );

$second = array('id','name','age','school');

foreach ($second as $value) {
    if(isset($first[$value])){
        $final[$value] =  $first[$value];
    }

};
print_r($final);
```

Second Array flip and array merge

```
$first = ['id' => 11,'name' => 'name','age' => 18];
$second= array_flip(['id','name','age','school']);
foreach($second as $key => s$value){
    $value = '';
}
$result = array_merge($second, $first);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

try this

```
$a = ['id' => 11,'name' => 'name','age' => 18];
$b = array_flip(['id','name','age','school']);
foreach($b as $key => &$value){
    $value = '';
}
$result = array_merge($b, $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge

```
<?php
$array1 = array('id' => '11', 'name' => 'name', 'age' => 18);
$array2 = array('id','name','age','school');

$array3 = array_merge(array_fill_keys($array2, null), $array1);

print_r($array3);
?>
```